# Trigonometry Question: find Value of.....

Tags: trigonometry

Find value of $3 + \cos2x + \cos4x + \cos6x - 4\cos x\cos2x\cos3x$. I tried with $\cos A + \cos B$ identity but it was not simplifying.... Help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using that $2\cos\alpha\cos\beta=\cos(\alpha+\beta)+\cos(\alpha-\beta)$, we can write
$$4\cos x\cos 2x\cos 3x=2\cos 2x\cdot \left(\cos4x+\cos 2x\right)=\cos6x+\cos2x+\cos4x+1,$$
which immediately gives $2$ as the final result.

**Added**: the second equality follows from
\begin{align}
2\cos 2 x\cos 4x&=\cos(4x+2x)+\cos(4x-2x),\\
2\cos 2x \cos 2x&=\cos(2x+2x)+\cos(2x-2x).
\end{align}

Comment: Could you add a step extra as I couldn't get how 2cos2x(cos4x + cos2x) = cos 6x + cos 2x + cos 4x +1

Comment: @Sudhanshu Sure, please check the update.

Answer (score 2):

Try the other way - $2\cos a\cos b=\cos(a+b)+\cos(a-b)$

Answer (score 2):

Using [Prosthaphaeresis Formula,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)
$$\cos2x+\cos4x=2\cos3x\cos x$$ and using [Double-Angle Formula,](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Double-AngleFormulas.html)
$$1+\cos6x=2\cos^23x$$

$$\implies\cos2x+\cos4x+1+\cos6x=2\cos3x\cos x+2\cos^23x =2\cos3x(\cos x+\cos3x)$$

Again using Prosthaphaeresis Formula,$$\cos x+\cos3x=2\cos2x\cos x$$

Comment: @Sudhanshu, How about this?